# How to set String as an input parameter in spring boot using GenericStoredProcedure?

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

Here is the code I am trying

```
    {
        StoredProcedure procedure = new GenericStoredProcedure();
        procedure.setDataSource(dataSource);
        procedure.setSql("Process_Procedure");
        procedure.setFunction(false);

        SqlParameter[] declareparameters = {
                new SqlParameter(Types.INTEGER),
                new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR),
        };
        int a = 15;
        String c = "purchase";
        procedure.setParameters(declareparameters);
        procedure.compile();
        procedure.execute(a, c);
    }
```

I am getting the exception: Cannot convert class java.lang.String to SQL in NumberFormat

if I only have integer parameters, It works fine but here I have to insert a string parameter which gives me the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have more than one input parameter you have to pass Map<String, ?> or ParameterMapper to Execute method.
...

```
        int a = 15;
        String c = "purchase";
        procedure.setParameters(declareparameters);
        procedure.compile();
        procedure.execute(<here you have to pass a Map<String, ?> or ParameterMapper as input parameters>);
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/GenericStoredProcedure.html) you can find more details about **GenericStoredProcedure**.
Checking that link you can see that **GenericStoredProcedure** extends **StoredProcedure** and it's using Execute methods inherited from **StoredProcedure** class: "This implementation does not provide a typed method for invocation so executions must use one of the generic StoredProcedure.execute(java.util.Map) or StoredProcedure.execute(org.springframework.jdbc.core.ParameterMapper) methods."

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html#execute-java.util.Map-) you can find all the details about Execute method.